# How to center a div inside another div that covers all the page (not using flexbox)

Tags: html, css

I am trying to build a div that should cover all the visible page. Inside this div there should be another one placed in the center (horizontally and vertically). this is what I have done so far:

```css
.spinner-box {
    background-color: #0F83E8;
    background-size: cover;
}

.spinner {
    position: absolute;
    top: 40%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    background-color: #0000cc;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="spinner-box">
  <div class="spinner">
    my content
  </div>
</div>
```

The inner div is visible but I can't the backgroud color of the outer one.
I know this question has been asked many times but i can't find an example with a div covering all the page

Comment: Why doesn't `.spinner-box` have any layout styling?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0; 
}
.spinner-box {
    background-color: #0F83E8;
    background-size: cover;
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width:100%;
}

.spinner {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    background-color: #0000cc;
}
```

```html
<div class="spinner-box">
      <div class="spinner">
        my content
      </div>
    </div>
```

You need to add some styles to `.spinner-box`:

```css
.spinner-box {
    background-color: #0F83E8;
    background-size: cover;
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width:100%;
}

.spinner {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    background-color: #0000cc;
}
```

```html
<div class="spinner-box">
      <div class="spinner">
        my content
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: this solution works but I can see horizontal and vertical scrolbars even if the page is empty. How can I avoid them?

Comment: `margin:  0` to `body`

Comment: Just add `body {padding: 0; margin: 0; }`

Comment: no padding and margin don't work, is that because I have `body {box-sizing: border-box;}`?

Comment: I have updated my answer above with styles for `body`. `box-sizing` is not the problem.

Comment: great. many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There's a few factors here.

- The parent element hasn't been given the maximum dimensions to cover
  the viewport.
- The className is not a correct HTML attribute in this situation, is
  should be class.
- Browsers have default settings which may mean that the body for
  example has a margin so the whole viewport won't be covered.
- I don't know why the top of the element was set to 40% if it is to be
  centered that should be 50%. Of course if there is a reason for the
  40% reinstate it.

This snippet alters these

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.spinner-box {
  background-color: #0F83E8;
  rbackground-size: cover;
  position: relative;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

.spinner {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background-color: #0000cc;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="spinner-box">
  <div class="spinner">
    my content
  </div>
</div>
```